# Fck Editor - Update Panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, fckeditor

I can't get the fckeditors value [using editorName.Value] with in an updatepanel in Asp.net. When i remove the Update panel I got the value.How to get the value without removing Update panel?

Comment: Have you tried putting the fckeditor outside the update panel?

Comment: @Avinash.. fck editor is ckeditor now http://ckeditor.com/... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions on this thread:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1028530.aspx